# How to save nested data fom API response into a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API response

const response = [

{
id:1,
tags:[data:"save1"]
},

{
id:2,
tags:[data:"save2"]
},

{
id:3,
tags:[data:"save3"]
},

]

I want to save the data of all tags into a single array like below e.g

const newArr = [{save1},{save2},{save3}]

how can i achieve that

I am new to in this any help will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response` object you posted in the question doesn't seem to be in a valid format.

Assuming the below is the one you were trying to post,

```
const response = [

{ id:1, tags:[{data:"save1"}] },

{ id:2, tags:[{data:"save2"}] },

{ id:3, tags:[{data:"save3"}] }

]
```

You can iterate the object with a map function and then push the tags in an array like this:

```
const tagsArray = [];
response.map((res) => {
  tagsArray.push(res.tags[0].data);
})
```

If you print the tagsArray, the final result may look something like this:

```
["save1", "save2", "save3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the id/key

```
 const response = [

          { "id": 1, "tags": [ { "data":"save1" } ] },
          { "id": 2, "tags": [  ] },
          ]

          const transformed = response
          ?.map(item => ({id: item.id, data: item?.tags?.[0]?.data }))
          ?.filter(item => !!item.data)
```